# jQuery draggable div

Tags: jquery, drag

I want to create a draggable content like the iOS Facebook chat feature, so if you drag the content less than 50% from right, it will go right, if you drag it more than 50% from right, it will go left.

I have this:
HTML:

```
  <div class="chat-head">
    <a class="bg"></a>
     <div class="message">
      <p>Content</p></div>
 </div>
```

jQuery:

```
  $(function() {
    $( "#draggable" ).draggable();
  });
```

I don't know how to create the auto-align to the left/right feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jqueryui.com/draggable/#snap-to

> Snap the draggable to the inner or outer boundaries of a DOM element. Use the snap, snapMode (inner, outer, both), and snapTolerance (distance in pixels the draggable must be from the element when snapping is invoked) options.

Comment: How can I make it snap to left or right depending by div's position after dragging it?

Comment: It should do that automatically, if you set `snapTolerance` to the desired value. http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-snapTolerance